# Make UITextView in UIScrollView right aligned

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewCell that i want to have a Title and a detail. The detail could be a long text so i am using a custom cell with a label as the title and a UITextView (Green rectangle) embedded in a UIScrollView as the detail.

[image: Green TextView left aligned in UIScrollView]

I want the UITextView to be right aligned in the UIScrollView so it will look like this (assume the 'detail' is in a scrollView):

[image: Detail Cell]

So far i have tried playing with several constraints but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`textView.textAlignment = .right` should do the trick.

However I don't think it's conventional to solve something like this problem by embedding a textView inside a scrollView. A textView has scrolling functionality enabled by default if its text height is greater than the textViews height. So best to remove the scrollView and just use a textView

Comment: I want a horizontal scroll. My experience with putting a textview in a UITableViewCell is that it truncates the text and add an ellipsis. `textView.textAlignment = .right` aligns the text in the UItextView to the right, but i want to align the UITextView to the right of the UIScrollView

Comment: Would it be best to use a `UITextField` rather than a `UITextView` then if you are going to keep it as one line and make it scroll horizontally? I think that might make it a bit simpler.  If you want the textView to not cut off the text you can change its `lineBreakMode` to be `.byWordWrapping`